# What's the correct way to use slotLabelFormat on Fullcalendar v4?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have been trying to customize the slotLabelFormat on Fullcalendar v4, using a custom string like `'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY'` but i get a js "context.cmdFormatter is not a function" error.

I'm trying to use the moment plugin by setting " `plugins: [ 'moment', 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ]` " (i cannot use the import method to load moment), but then I get an "moment is not a function" error.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages-premium/timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages-premium/resource-timeline/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/moment/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages-premium/timeline/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages-premium/resource-common/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages-premium/resource-timeline/main.js'></script>
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'moment','interaction', 'resourceTimeline' ],
      locale: 'es',

      now: '2019-08-07',
      editable: true,

      scrollTime: '00:00'
      ,
      eventClick: function (info) {
                   alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('View: ' + info.view.type);
                return false;
            },
      header: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear'
      },
      defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
      views: {
        resourceTimelineDay: {
          buttonText: 'day',
          slotDuration: '01:00'
        },
        resourceTimelineWeek: {
          type: 'resourceTimelineWeek',
          //titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' },
          slotLabelFormat: 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY',
          duration: { weeks: 1 },
          slotDuration: {days: 1},
          buttonText: 'week'
        }
      },
 dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
      navLinks: true,
      resourceAreaWidth: '20%',
      resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
      resources: [
        { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
        { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
        { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
        { id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D', children: [
          { id: 'd1', title: 'Room D1' },
          { id: 'd2', title: 'Room D2' }
        ] },
        { id: 'e', title: 'Auditorium E' },
        { id: 'f', title: 'Auditorium F', eventColor: 'red' },
        { id: 'g', title: 'Auditorium G' },
        { id: 'h', title: 'Auditorium H' },
        { id: 'i', title: 'Auditorium I' },
        { id: 'j', title: 'Auditorium J' },
        { id: 'k', title: 'Auditorium K' },
        { id: 'l', title: 'Auditorium L' },
        { id: 'm', title: 'Auditorium M' },
        { id: 'n', title: 'Auditorium N' },
        { id: 'o', title: 'Auditorium O' },
        { id: 'p', title: 'Auditorium P' },
        { id: 'q', title: 'Auditorium Q' },
        { id: 'r', title: 'Auditorium R' },
        { id: 's', title: 'Auditorium S' },
        { id: 't', title: 'Auditorium T' },
        { id: 'u', title: 'Auditorium U' },
        { id: 'v', title: 'Auditorium V' },
        { id: 'w', title: 'Auditorium W' },
        { id: 'x', title: 'Auditorium X' },
        { id: 'y', title: 'Auditorium Y' },
        { id: 'z', title: 'Auditorium Z' }
      ],
      events: [
        { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2019-08-07T02:00:00', end: '2019-08-07T07:00:00', title: 'event 1',color: '#378006' },
        { id: '2', resourceId: 'c', start: '2019-08-07T05:00:00', end: '2019-08-07T22:00:00', title: 'event 2',color: '#378006' },
        { id: '3', resourceId: 'd', start: '2019-08-06', end: '2019-08-08', title: 'event 3',color: 'red' },
        { id: '4', resourceId: 'e', start: '2019-08-07T03:00:00', end: '2019-08-07T08:00:00', title: 'event 4',color: '#378006' },
        { id: '5', resourceId: 'f', start: '2019-08-07T00:30:00', end: '2019-08-07T02:30:00', title: 'event 5',color: '#378006' }
      ]
    });

    calendar.render();
  });

</script>
<style>

  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution by myself, you need to add the real moment js from the moment website (i used https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js) or it wont work.  Sad documentation is not clear on that.